# How do I completely disable JavaScript errors using VS 2008 and IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

I am trying to prevent VS from breaking on JS errors.

I have the following settings:

In IE, under `Tools->Internet Settings->Advanced (tab)->Browsing`, 
`Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)` and `Disable script debugging (Other)` are checked.

In VS, under `Debug->Exceptions->Common Language Runtime Exceptions`, 
`JScript Exceptions` (thrown and user-unhandled) are unchecked.

In VS, under `Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time`, `Script` is unchecked.

There are some JavaScript errors that I just don't care about and it is driving me insane having to deal with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2009/04/06/disabling-script-debugging-in-vs-2008-ie8.aspx)
This is more prominent solution rather switching to firefox. i tried this and it worked for me like charm.
check out alternative work around in same document if you dont want to choose silverlight tool..

Comment: Hi , i have the same problem .. when i try this command in cmd >> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AD7Metrics\Engine\{F200A7E7-DEA5-11D0-B854-00A0244A1DE2} /v ProgramProvider /d {4FF9DEF4-8922-4D02-9379-3FFA64D1D639} /f , it gives me an ERROR: Access is denied

Comment: Can you help me ? , i want to use the 2nd option in your link , which is add in registry.. i dont want to install silverlight.. but when i execute the said command above , i get an error Access is denied.. what will i do to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do that. VS will auto enable the settings in IE when you run the page under debug (and will keep those settings as long as the IE window is open).

Obvious workarounds:

Set default browser to Firefox

Don't run in debug mode

Comment: Unfortunately using FF as default and not running in Debug are not available options :(